# I am having trouble with requiring encryption

Tags: powershell, vpn

I have created a powershell script to set up a VPN connection. It seems to work well enough except for when I set the encryption to required, the script will not run. If I set encryption level to optional, I can go back into the VPN settings and set it to required and it works perfectly. I have tried a few variations to the script but had no luck.

```
Add-VpnConnection -name "" -ServerAddress "" -TunnelType L2tp -AuthenticationMethod "Pap" -EncryptionLevel "Optional" -SplitTunneling -PassThru -L2tpPsk "" 
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName '' -DestinationPrefix
```

Comment: Please update your question with the specific issues or errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

PAP is unencrypted by design as outlined on [RFC1334](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1334). So requiring encryption won't work. But it seems you MIGHT be setting up a connection to a Meraki. There's a known issue with this cmdlet on setting up a connection to Meraki, you can use the OPTIONAL parameter value and just go into the connection detail and change it to required. I won't know more than that unless you provide more information :).

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply! Yes, you are absolutely right! I am using a Meraki. Please forgive my lack of information, I am not well versed with VPN protocol. What other information would be valuable to this question?

Comment: So since this a connection to the Meraki. The PowerShell cmdlet has an issue as you cannot specify "required" on the EncryptionLevel parameter. You can leave it as Optional and then change it to "required" on the connection detail after you created it with the cmdlet.

Alternatively, you can just follow the wizard via GUI using the Cisco documentation: https://documentation.meraki.com/MX/Client_VPN/Client_VPN_OS_Configuration

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem @Chris_Ritchie! If this answered your question, please accept this answer so that others can reference this when having issues with Meraki on Windows. :)